# Unable to delete a folder on Windows with a .git in it

Tags: windows, git, powershell

If I start a PowerShell as a regular user (not admin) and run

```
cd Desktop
mkdir test
cd test
git init
cd ..
```

I then cant delete the folder via PowerShell. I have tried the following commands as admin and as the current user.

```
rm -r test                 # -> no access permission
rmdir test                 # -> no access permission
del -r test                # -> no access permission
del test                   # -> no access permission
```

It prints

```
 + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (.git:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

But I don't understand why I can't remove folders with a .git folder in them.

Comment: Very nice [mre]. Immediately reproduced. The folder can be deleted in Explorer without any problems.

Comment: A `cmd` and `rmdir /s /q test` works. I think Powershell s.... :-)

Comment: Are you cd'd in the directory of the .git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In order to remove [a directory that contains] *hidden items*, PowerShell's [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) cmdlet requires passing the `-Force` switch**:

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force test
```

The **shortest form of this command** (for *interactive* rather than scripting use), using the **platform-neutral `ri` alias** and PowerShell's so-called *elastic syntax*, where it is sufficient to specify a *prefix* of a parameter name (such as `-r` for `-Recurse`), as long as that prefix is *unambiguous*):

```
ri -r -fo test
```

<sup>Note how a *two*-letter prefix is required for `-Force`, because `-f` alone is ambiguous: it could also refer to the `-Filter` parameter.</sup>

- `git init` creates a `.git` subdirectory that is assigned the `Hidden` attribute on Windows (on Unix-like platforms, the fact that the name starts with `.` alone makes the directory a hidden one).
- On Windows, `rm`, `del`, `rmdir` are simply built-in *aliases* of `Remove-Item`, the single cmdlet used to remove both files and directories (removal of the latter requiring `-Recurse` if the directory is not empty).
  (On Unix-like platforms, only `del` is defined as an aliases, so as not to shadow the platform-native `rm` and `rmdir` *utilities*.)

  - `ri` is a *platform*-neutral alias derived from the name `Remove-Item`, and therefore preferable.
  - To see all aliases defined for a given command use `Get-Alias -Definition $name`; e.g.:

    ```
    Get-Alias -Definition Remove-Item
    ```

Note: While it is arguably beneficial for PowerShell to require explicit *opt-in* via `-Force` in order to delete hidden items - so that you don't accidentally delete items whose existence you may not be aware of - the ***error message* is suboptimal**, in that the problem isn't one of *permissions*.